# I want to make a program that recognize a button that is in the League of Legends client

Tags: java, python

I want to make a program that recognize a button that is in the League of Legends client, and when the queue's button shows up the mouse instantly click on it.

Its a sort of a AutoAccept Client...

There is already a program that someone did, but it has so many unnecessary things and it does not work very well....

How do I do to recognize a element inside a program to make my mouse move there when it shows up?

I can try to code this in any language, just gimme a tip pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a program that takes a screenshot every 100ms, use a recognition algorithm of your choice and then (optionally) performs a mouse click. There are enough libraries that can screenshot for you, you should be able to recognise the button by colour and location and every language should have some method of controlling the mouse.

Comment: I did this 2 years ago, I could create smurf accounts and level up them almost fully automatically with this code https://github.com/vmnog/xpautoboost, it needs some adjustments to make it work because I was not so good at programming and python at the time, but it works just like you said, with screenshots and image recognition, then it sends commands to mouse and keyboard to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

Sikulix (can be paired with python) is a perfect tool to use for this. It scans over your screen constantly, and if the image in question pops up (the accept button) you can click on it.

You will have to take a screenshot and likely store it as .png so the program knows what it is looking for.

Google Sikulix.

Comment: acctually I made it so far, but with another lib, but its done =D , you can take a look at the source https://github.com/vmnog/AutoAcceptClient